# How can I remove this duplicate code in my code while still getting what I is needed

Tags: php

This first code below is the duplicate in my code :

```
php $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","task");
 $results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM note");
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
```

I want to remove it while I still can get the data that I want. 
How can I be  able to do it?

```
<?php $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","task");
 $results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM note");
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
$id = $row['id'];


    echo '<button class="call_modal" style="cursor:pointer; width: 150px; height: 60px;">' .$row['title']. '</button>';
    echo "<a href='update.php?id=$id'>edit</a>";
    echo '&nbsp; &nbsp;';
    echo "<a href='delete.php?id=$id'>delete</a>";


}
?>

<?php $results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM note"); ?>
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { ?>
<div class="modal">
<div class="modal_close close"></div>
<div class="modal_main">
<div class="note">


<?php
   echo '<br><br>';
       echo '<div class="padding">'.$row['title'].'';
        echo '<br><br><br><br>';
    echo ''.$row['note'].'</div>';
    echo '<br><br><br><br><br>';
   echo '<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
        </form>'
?>


<img src="x.png" class="close" style="line-height: 12px;
     margin-top: 1px;
     margin-right: 2px;
     position:absolute;
     top:0;
     right:0;
     width: 15px;
     height:15px;">
</div>
</div>

<?php
}?>
```

check this out if this is true:

```
<?php $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","task");
 $results = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM note");
 $rows = mysqli_fetch_all($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
 foreach ($rows as $row) {
     $id = $row['id'];


         echo '<button class="call_modal" style="cursor:pointer; width: 150px; height: 60px;">' .$row['title']. '</button>';
         echo "<a href='update.php?id=$id'>edit</a>";
         echo '&nbsp; &nbsp;';
         echo "<a href='delete.php?id=$id'>delete</a>";

}
?>


<?php foreach ($rows as $row) { ?>
<div class="modal">
<div class="modal_close close"></div>
<div class="modal_main">
<div class="note">


<?php
   echo '<br><br>';
       echo '<div class="padding">'.$row['title'].'';
        echo '<br><br><br><br>';
    echo ''.$row['note'].'</div>';
    echo '<br><br><br><br><br>';
   echo '<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
        </form>'
?>


<img src="x.png" class="close" style="line-height: 12px;
     margin-top: 1px;
     margin-right: 2px;
     position:absolute;
     top:0;
     right:0;
     width: 15px;
     height:15px;">
</div>
</div>

<?php
}?>
```

Comment: If you don't show any data, then no one know what you mean by "duplicate".

Comment: It's in the first code I showed

Comment: The only duplicate I see is that you're executing the same query twice. I suppose you could use `$results->data_seek(0)` to reset it so you can loop through it again.

Comment: Should I put it after the first duplicate code?

Comment: You can put it somewhere between the two `while` loops.

Comment: Dude I'm planning to get the data row by row in the database in the second while, why do I can't get it?

Comment: Store the result in loop 1 in an array, then use that array in place of second query call.

Comment: Alternatively, after the first query do something like `$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC);` and then replace both `while` loops with a `foreach ($rows as $row)` loop.

Comment: I'm new to foreach, an you guys still be help because I still have to figure out how to do it as well as a little eat.

Comment: can u post a code on how to do it? the foreach?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to not execute the same query twice you have to re-use the result. There are several ways to do that:

#### Reset the result

Example:

```
$results = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM note");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    // do something
}

mysqli_data_seek($results, 0);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    // do something else
}
```

**Why this is necessary:** `mysqli_fetch_array` updates the internal pointer in `$results` that tells it what the next row is. When the first loop finishes, that internal pointer is set to *beyond* the last row, to indicate there are no more rows available. When your second loop starts, that pointer is still set there so it will not have any results to loop through. Using `mysqli_data_seek` you can manually set the pointer back to the beginning.

#### Fetch the results once

Example:

```
$results = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM note");
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // do something
}

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // do something else
}
```

Using `mysqli_fetch_all` will retrieve all rows as an array. You can then loop over that array as many times as you want. I'm explicitly asking for `MYSQLI_ASSOC` results, since you're using `$row['id']` and `$row['note']`. `mysqli_fetch_all()` defaults to using `MYSQLI_NUM` results, which would not allow you to do that.

AFAIK, this is the most common approach, but it has a downside: you're retrieving all results into memory. If your query has a lot of results or if your application is already using a lot of memory, this may be a problem.

> Since you said you're new to `foreach`, here's a short explanation of how it is different from other looping methods:
>
> ```
> foreach ($rows as $index => $row) {
> }
>
> // is the same as:
> for ($index = 0; $index < count($rows); $index++) {
>     $row = $rows[$index];
> }
>
> // or:
> $index = 0;
> while ($index < count($rows)) {
>     $row = $rows[$index];
> }
>
> // and if you're not interested in it, you don't need to ask for the $index:
> foreach ($rows as $row) {
> }
> ```
>
> The main difference is that `foreach` also works easily on non-numeric arrays. For example:
>
> ```
> foreach ($row as $column => $value) {
>     echo $column . ': ' . $value . '<br>';
>     // id: 123
>     // title: Note title
>     // note: Lorem ipsum ...
> }
> ```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192525/discussion-on-answer-by-rickdenhaan-how-can-i-remove-this-duplicate-code-in-my-c).